# Run multiple procedures at the same time in netlogo

Tags: performance, command, netlogo, procedures, agents

Hello i have the following code:

```
        to go
            move
            play-papelvstije
            play-papelvsrock
            play-tijevsrock
            play-tijevspapel
            play-rockvspapel
            play-rockvstije
        end


        to play-rockvspapel
            ask turtles with [color = red]
                [
                let nearby other turtles in-radius 1
                if any? nearby with [color = green]
                [
                set color green 
                ]
                ]
        end

        to play-papelvstije 
            ask turtles with [color = green]
            [
            let nearby other turtles in-radius 1
            if any? nearby with [color = blue]
            [
            set color blue  
            ]
            ]
        end

       to play-tijevsrock
            ask turtles with [color = blue]
            [ 
            let nearby other turtles in-radius 1
            if any? nearby with [color = red]
            [
            set color red  
            ] 
            ]
        end

        to play-rockvstije
            ask turtles with [color = red]
            [
            let nearby other turtles in-radius 1
            if any? nearby with [color = blue]
            [
            set color red 
            ]
            ]
            end

        to play-papelvsrock
            ask turtles with [color = green]
            [
            let nearby other turtles in-radius 1
            if any? nearby with [color = red]
            [
            set color green 
            ]
            ]
        end

        to play-tijevspapel
            ask turtles with [color = blue]
            [
            let nearby other turtles in-radius 1
            if any? nearby with [color = green]
            [
            set color blue
            ]
            ]
        end
```

So as you can see, i run this procedures play-papelvstije play-papelvsrock          play-tijevsrock, play-tijevspapel, play-rockvspapel, play-rockvstije in this exactly order, so when run the simulation i get an slant in my results, because the first command to run is the one that have an increase population in the end, so what i want to do is finding a way to run this procedures but with one just command. I have tried with "foreach" and "map" commands, however i have not gotten results. Anny suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

one solution can be to not directly ask blue turtles but for all turtles ... something like

```
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 100 [
   set color red
   setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
  ]
  ask n-of 10 turtles [
   set color green 
  ]
  ask n-of 10 turtles with [color = red][
   set color blue 
  ]


  reset-ticks
end

to go
  move
  changeColor
  tick
end

to move
  ask turtles [
    rt random-float 90
    lt random-float 90
    fd 1
  ]
end

to changeColor
  ask turtles [
    let mycolor color
    let nearby other turtles in-radius 1
    if mycolor = blue [
       if any? nearby with [color = green]
        [
          set color blue
        ]
       if any? nearby with [color = red]
        [
          set color red  
        ]  
    ]
    if mycolor = green [
       if any? nearby with [color = red]
        [
          set color green 
        ]
       if any? nearby with [color = blue]
        [
          set color blue  
        ]
    ]
    if mycolor = red [
       if any? nearby with [color = red][
        if any? nearby with [color = blue]
        [
          set color red 
        ]
        if any? nearby with [color = green]
        [
          set color green 
        ]
       ]
    ]
  ]
end
```